# Product of rank-2 spherical tensors

Tags: quantum-mechanics, atomic-physics, tensor-calculus, multipole-expansion, wigner-eckart

I have been reading up a lot of material on spherical tensors to try and help me with a calculation of the electric quadrupole energy shift of an atom, and have run into a block due to my lack of knowledge.
I am trying to perform the calculation $\nabla E^* \otimes \nabla E$ where $\nabla E$ is the electric field gradient tensor of rank 2, and the energy shift is directly proportional to the result of this.

I can construct the gradient tensor by $\nabla E_q^{(k)} = \sum_{q1}\sum_{q2} \left<k_1 q_1 k_2 q_2 | k q\right> \nabla_{q1}^{(k1)} E_{q2}^{(k2)}$, with the usual notation for the rank-1 spherical tensor components $\nabla^{(k1)}$ and $E^{(k2)}$, and obtaining the complex conjugate through $T_q^{(k)} = (-1)^qT_{-q}^{(k)}$. I use the Rank-2 terms $\nabla E_0^{(2)}, \nabla E_{\pm 1}^{(2)}, \nabla E_{\pm 2}^{(2)}$ for the rest of the calculations.
The cartesian components of the tensor, $\partial Ex/\partial x, \partial Ex/\partial y$ etc. that make up the spherical tensor are themselves complex numbers.

The product $\nabla E^* \otimes \nabla E$ results in a bunch of terms (25 terms) of rank $0\leq k \leq 4$  which I can then plug into another expression to calculate energy.

My issue comes from when I then do the multiplication of $\nabla E^* \otimes \nabla E$, I am getting complex results for the energy, due to the fact the resulting Tensor $\nabla E^* \otimes \nabla E$ does not seem to cancel out all of the complex components in the electric field gradients.

So I have a few questions,

1. Does the general working I am doing make sense?
2. When multiplying the two gradient tensors together do I need to inclulde ALL rank components, instead of just the Rank 2 parts?
3. Is it reasonable to expect that the results $\nabla E^* \otimes \nabla E$ are purely real?